# ember integration test error. dealing with asynchronous side-effects

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, integration-testing, ember-testing

I'm trying ember's integration testing package (http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/integration/) but I am getting this error

```
Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun.    
You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run
```

I've made a JSBin to reproduce this error: http://jsbin.com/InONiLe/9, which we can see by opening up the browser's console.

I believe what's causing this error is the line `data.set('isLoaded', true);` in the `load()` method of `App.Posts`. (Link to code: http://jsbin.com/InONiLe/9/edit)

Now, if I wrap the `data.set('isLoaded', true);` line in an `Ember.run()`, then it will work as expected and the test will pass.

However, I am using this pattern for a lot of my models and I don't want to just wrap every `.set()` with an `Ember.run()` (transitions also trigger the same error). I also don't want to change application code for the sake of making the test work.

Is there something else I can do to fix the error?

Note: I am purposely not returning a promise in the model hook because otherwise the UI is blocked until the promise is resolved. I want the transition to the route to happen immediately so that I can display a loading spinner.

Answer (score 3):

When you use some methods, that triggers async code, like ajax, setInterval, the indexeddb api etc. You will need to delegate the resolved callbacks of theses methods to `Ember.run`, so ember will queue these operations in your runloop and it ensure that application is in sync. So changing your code for this is the correct way to handle this:

```
App.Posts = Ember.Object.create({
  load: function() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {      
      var data = Ember.Object.create();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs'
      }).then(function() {
        data.set('isLoaded', true);
        Ember.run(null, resolve, data);        
      }, reject);      
    });    
  }
});
```

Other advise is to always use the `Ember.RSVP.Promise`, because is more compatible with Ember than `$.Defered`. $.Deferred is returned by `$.ajax`.

Here is an updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/InONiLe/10/edit

**UPDATE**

Because in your case you don't want to return a promise, so just drop it, and just return the data itself:

```
App.Posts = Ember.Object.create({
  load: function() {    
    var data = Ember.Object.create();    
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs'
    }).then(function() {        
      Ember.run(function() {
        data.set('isLoaded', true);
      });                
    }, function(xhr) {        
      Ember.run(function() {
        // if using some ember stuff put here
      });
    });
    return data;
  }
});
```

Here is the jsbin showing this working http://jsbin.com/InONiLe/17/edit

I hope it helps

Comment: I do not want to return a promise in the model hook because the transition won't happen until the promise is resolved. That is why I return an Ember object instead, so that the transition happens immediately and we see the Loading message, follow by an update to the dom when the response comes back.