# How to do Ember unit testing with asynchronous routes?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js

I'm using the functionality described in the [Ember.js Asynchronous Routing](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/) guide. Namely, I'm returning a promise from my asynchronous route's `model` hook to delay transitioning to the route, which works as expected.

However, it breaks the ability to unit test my app. When I run my tests, I get the following error in the console:

> Assertion failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the
>   run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous
>   side-effects in an Ember.run

I've wrapped all code with asynchronous side-effects in `Ember.run`, but I still get the error.

Here's a JSFiddle with a minimal example: **http://jsfiddle.net/nRHfv/3/**

The example is based on the Ember Starter Kit and the test runner it comes with. It has a working asynchronous index route. If you set `testing: false` to `true` in the `_config` object (line 10), it will turn on the test suite, and you should see the above error in your console.

My asynchronous route's `model` hook is on line 38. I've tried several variations on wrapping the code in `Ember.run`. For example, I've tried defining the promise outside of `Ember.run`, doing all the asynchronous stuff inside, and then returning the promise outside. I've also tried wrapping just the contents of `then()` in `Ember.run`, like I've seen on some other answers (e.g. [ember integration test error. dealing with asynchronous side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664505/ember-integration-test-error-dealing-with-asynchronous-side-effects)).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For someone looking at this error might want to look at this video about ember run loop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLgPBM72LQw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching, I found [this notable comment](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/guide-asynchronous-side-effects-in-testing/2905/17) on [Guide: Asynchronous side-effects in testing](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/guide-asynchronous-side-effects-in-testing/2905) on the Ember.js discussion forum by [EmberSherpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172894/ember-sherpa):

> BTW, there was a library released today that's designed to replace
>   $.getJSON and makes this process a lot easier  https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax

I tried the ic-ajax library, and it worked! After digging in to see what it's doing, here's how I should have written my asynchronous route's `model` hook:

```
var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  Ember.$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      json: '{ "text": "Hello from Ember.js" }',
      delay: 0.25
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      Ember.run(null, resolve, response);
    }
  })
});

return promise.then(function (response) {
  return response;
});
```

I guess jQuery promises are not interchangeable with `Ember.RSVP.Promise` when testing (but they are for triggering asynchronous routing actions).

Here's an updated JSFiddle with asynchronous routing and testing working: **http://jsfiddle.net/nRHfv/5/**

I think I'm going to stick with [ic-ajax](https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax) for the sake of cleaner code, and because of the ability to load static fixtures instead of live API endpoints when testing.